# Imprimir tablas de multiplicar con resultado en números romanos

Tags: python

Buenas noches a todos.

Estoy desarrollando un ejercicio en el cual tengo que mostrar las tablas de multiplicar del 1 al 10 con el resultado de cada una en romano.

> Tengo desarrollada la mayor parte del ejercicio pero de verdad que ya
>   no entiendo como imprimir los números de acuerdo al resultado, por
>   ahora solo la tabla del 10 me sale correcta mostrando los números
>   romanos correctos pero en las demás tablas se me descuadra y aun no entiendo como poner las unidades.

### Python.

```
def captura():
    numero_tabla = int(input("Escriba el numero de tablas a realizar: "))
    unidades_romanos = ['I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V', 'VI', 'VII', 'VIII', 'IX']
    decenas_romanos = ['X', 'XX', 'XXX', 'XL', 'L', 'LX', 'LXX', 'LXXX','XC', 'C']
    numeros_escritos = ['uno', 'dos', 'tres', 'cuatro', 'cinco', 'seis', 'siete', 'ocho', 'nueve', 'diez']
    tablas=range(1,11)
    for elemento in tablas:
        producto = numero_tabla * elemento
        decenas = producto / 10
        de = int(decenas)
        recorrido = de - 1
        escritos = elemento - 1
        print(numero_tabla, "X", numeros_escritos[escritos], "=", decenas_romanos[recorrido])
captura()
```

[image: Ejemplo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saludos puedes realizar algo como esto:

Crear una función que convierta los números enteros a romanos:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def write_roman(num):

    roman = OrderedDict()
    roman[1000] = "M"
    roman[900] = "CM"
    roman[500] = "D"
    roman[400] = "CD"
    roman[100] = "C"
    roman[90] = "XC"
    roman[50] = "L"
    roman[40] = "XL"
    roman[10] = "X"
    roman[9] = "IX"
    roman[5] = "V"
    roman[4] = "IV"
    roman[1] = "I"

    def roman_num(num):
        for r in roman.keys():
            x, y = divmod(num, r)
            yield roman[r] * x
            num -= (r * x)
            if num <= 0:
                break

    return "".join([a for a in roman_num(num)])
```

forma de uso:

```
print write_roman(11)
#salida
XI
```

bien ahora con las tablas de multiplicar:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def write_roman(num):

    roman = OrderedDict()
    roman[1000] = "M"
    roman[900] = "CM"
    roman[500] = "D"
    roman[400] = "CD"
    roman[100] = "C"
    roman[90] = "XC"
    roman[50] = "L"
    roman[40] = "XL"
    roman[10] = "X"
    roman[9] = "IX"
    roman[5] = "V"
    roman[4] = "IV"
    roman[1] = "I"

    def roman_num(num):
        for r in roman.keys():
            x, y = divmod(num, r)
            yield roman[r] * x
            num -= (r * x)
            if num <= 0:
                break

    return "".join([a for a in roman_num(num)])


def tablaDeMultiplicar():
  n = int(input('Ingrese la tabla:'))
  inicio = 1
  fin = 13
  multiplicando = write_roman(n)
  for i in range(inicio, fin):
    multiplicador = write_roman(i)
    total = n*i
    totalRomanos = write_roman(total)
    print(multiplicando, 'x', multiplicador,'=',totalRomanos)
tablaDeMultiplicar()
```

finalmente el resultado:
[image: result roman table]
Espero te sirva y suerte..!!